# Formatting text in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I am styling text but am not able to get what I want like -:
I want this text below [image]

look like this -:
[image]

how do I do it can anyone help?

Comment: can you post your current code ?

Comment: Have you tried RichText?

Comment: no, I haven't tried rich text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each word on a new line

```
String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

Text(
  text.replaceAll(" ", "\n"),
),
```

`text.replaceAll(" ", "\n")` will replace all space with \n(new line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use \n (optn + shift + 7) to make a new line inside you're String.

```
Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Hello \nWorld',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 0.7
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Use textAlign to make your text align in the center (default is align left).

Comment: but what if there are 3 letter words and all are coming from the list?

Comment: You can use a Column with the three Text widgets as children and align them to the center. If you could provide us with parts of your code I could better understand your problem (if this is not the solution already).

Comment: `List<String> newname = [
    'Single BedSheet',
    'Double BedSheet',
    'Queen size Bedsheet',
    'King size Bedsheet',
    'Single BedSheet',
    'Double BedSheet',
    'Queen size Bedsheet',
    'King size Bedsheet',
    'Single BedSheet',
    'Double BedSheet',
  ];`                                       suppose this is the list.

Comment: So you want to show the strings of this list beneath each other? For this you can use the ListView.builder. User `ListView.builder(itemCount: newname.length, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {return Container(child: Text(newname[index]))},)` now it will give you all Strings from the list underneath each other you just have to style the Text and you can give the Container a size, width, color, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its seem like by your comment you have a dynamic data. Since your question is not very clear, I will give you sample example to handle dynamic Data.

```
List a = ['Hello World', 'Hello', 'World'];
    ListView(
              children: a.map((e) {
            if (e == "Hello") {
              return Text(
                e,
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              );
            } else if (e == "World") {
              return Text(
                e,
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              );
            } else {
              return Text(
                e,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              );
            }
          }).toList()),
```

**Code Explanation**

1). I have declare a Random List of String.

2). Then I used List View to handle dynamic list.

3). I put iteration and use a Text widget and put some style according to my Requirment.

> you can put condition by yourself what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use \n to make a new line

**Code:**

```
 Center(
              child: Text('Hello Guys, Thanks \nfor visiting our website \nFlutter Examples.com',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22), 
                textAlign: TextAlign.center)
              )
```